# Determining Class Responsibility and Collaborators

Tags: oop, single-responsibility-principle

I'm using ActiveRecord to maintain information about users. The User class has the expected load(), insert(), update(), and delete() methods, setters, getters, and a few others. But I am having trouble deciding whether or not certain other methods should be included in the User class, or handled by collaborators.

Here's an example:

There are several transactions that a user might request that require confirmation. This is handled in a conventional way -- sending an email to the user with a link; clicking the link confirms that the user does indeed want the transaction to proceed. A hash of the verification key and it's expiration date/time persist as part of the user record.

Where should I draw the line in this process? Should there be a collaborator that handles verification (for example by taking the plain-text verification key from the query string and accepting a User object as a param)? Or should this be handled internally by the User class (passing the plain-text verification key in a method call)?

The very next thing that would happen upon verification, of course, is that the transaction would proceed requiring an update to the active record -- and there, it seems to me, the User class must have responsibility.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delegate this task to a collaborator, which manages a `confirmations` table.

You would use the `Confirmation` model to track all confirmation requirements.  The model will belong to `User`, as well as manage the confirmation hash and the action-to-be-confirmed (e.g. `activate_account`, `change_password` or `change_email` etc.).

The `Confirmation` controller would be responsible for validating the confirmation hash and chaining the appropriate action on the appropriate model (e.g. `activate_account` -> `user.activate()`, `change_password` -> `user.setPassword()` etc.) and remove the `Confirmation` from the `confirmations` table upon successful completion.

This will allow for better separation of logic, as well as allow you to scale better, e.g. to entertain more than one pending confirmation for a given user (say confirmation to change password *and* confirmation to change something else.)

Comment: @Vlad - Thanks for the reality check. This is no doubt the correct choice!